# Jekyll redirects to a 404 and does not render post.md

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I want my index.md seen at

- http://jtm-lis.github.io/Julien_Tremblay_McLellan/

to redirect to pages I have written in markdown

I tried implementing, post_url variable , such as documented
in order to successful redirect to a page written in markdown without success, as it points to a 404 at

```
[Name of Link]({% post_url 2010-07-21-name-of-post %})
```

http://www.jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts

At first I thought this was an error from the for loop, so I added the link manually as detailed in the documentation specifically for pages written in markdown.

### index.md

```
# Index of all my content

[Library Carpentry Workshop July 2020]({% post_url 2020-07-27-library-carpentry-workshop-american-university-notes %})


<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### _config.yml

```
theme: jekyll-theme-slate
url: https://jtm-lis.github.io
baseurl: /Julien_Tremblay_McLellan #NO TRAILING SLASH
title: Julien Tremblay McLellan's Website
author: Julien Tremblay McLellan
email: jtremc@gmail.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
# social links
twitter_username: jtm-lis # DO NOT include the @ character, or else the build will fail!
github_username:  jtm-lis # DO NOT include the @ character, or else the build will fail!

show_excerpts: true # set to false to remove excerpts on the homepage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is that the link does not use the `site.baseurl`,
so instead of linking to

`https://jtm-lis.github.io/Julien_Tremblay_McLellan/2020/07/27/library-carpentry-workshop-american-university-notes.html`

you are linking to

`https://jtm-lis.github.io/2020/07/27/library-carpentry-workshop-american-university-notes.html` which does not exist.

The fix is easy though, you just need to add `site.baseurl` to your link as in

```
[Name of Link]({% post_url 2010-07-21-name-of-post | prepend: site.baseurl %})
```

When doing this, you may encounter an other problem on your `localhost` environment, since most likely your `site.baseurl` folder does not exist there. So it will work on your live site, but has broken links in your local environment.

To work normally on `localhost` just override the `baseurl` property when you serve it:

```
jekyll serve --baseurl ""
```

or if you work with bundler

```
bundler exec jekyll serve --baseurl ""
```